# Debugging kills Apppool

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an application which worked fine until yesterday.
Today I cannot run the application using F5. I receive an error "Unable to start ASP.NET Debugging".

When this message appears, the app-pool is stopped. No matter how often I restart the app-pool, debugging stops it again.

I DID NOT change one line of code. But what I did was changing my windows-(domain-user)password.

I already rebooted.

Any clue? Any logfile where I might look at?

Comment: PDB files are same? Any modifications to PDB file or source? Is your AppPool runs on same windows identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the application pool running as your domain account? Did you update the password in the application pool as well?

Have you checked the Event Viewer to see why the application pool isn't starting?

Comment: Arg. Must have forgotten that I also used my user account for the apppool. %-) thx Kick me if I ask the same question again in about four months ...

Comment: nah, we'll just mark it as a duplicate ;) Glad it solved the problem